# Opera Mini HTML5 video problems with playing

Tags: html, video, opera-mini

I have a HTML5 video tag on my website, every browser is playing it correctly. The problem is when I'm on Opera Mini and when I press play button - video is not starting and I'm getting info: This file can not be downloaded. When I press play second time it's starting correctly.

```
<video preload="none" id="videoAbout" controls poster="/images/video/video.jpg">    
      <source src="/video/openform-final.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="/video/openform-final.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="/video/openform-final.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Video is not supported.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera Mini does not support html5 so your video tag won't work

Which is why it won't support the video tag.

Source http://www.opera.com/mobile/specs/: